# Unit testing 101 - throwing an exception from within my unit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I asked a related question. I want to give both those posters credit for the information that they provided based on my inadequate information in the post. They have lead me to this question here. If I can understand this, then off I go to credit the posters who have helped me thus far as well as any of you helpful folk.

I have an interface

```
public interface InventoryRepository
{


    List<Location> GetLocations();
    List<InventoryItem> GetItems();
    List<InventoryItem> GetItems(int LocationId);
    HomeMadeItem GetHomeMadeItem(int ItemId);
    StoreBoughtItem GetStoreBoughtItem(int ItemId);
    Location GetLocation(int LocationId);
    int SaveHomeMadeItem(HomeMadeItem item);
    string DeleteItem(int id);

}
```

My MVC app is going to be happy as a pig in ... well you know, so long as this contract is satisfied. Woot, all is good.

So you see, I have a DeleteItem method that is implemented thusly:

```
    public string DeleteItem(int ItemId)
    {

        using (var context = new InventoryEF())
        {
            var item = context.InventoryItems.Find(ItemId);
            if (item != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    context.InventoryItems.Remove(item);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return "";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    return e.InnerException.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Id not found for delete";
            }
        }
    }
```

I can very easily devise a unit test that tests the return value on successful deletion or item not found. I do not know how to devise a unit test that demonstrates the correct return value for a thrown exception.

Moq was suggested. But my original question was not clear enough for me to be certain that this is the correct approach.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to devise this unit test?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean but a lot of unit testing frameworks have an ExpectedException check. Which framework are you using?

Comment: Separate the processing logic from the exception handling/status logic. Test the processing logic as a unit test. Test the status logic at a higher level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (var context = new InventoryEF())
```

That is a problem since you are instantiating a dependency directly. You need to make the context injectable somehow (which is a part of different discussion).

Once you have InventoryEF a dependency, you can mock any of the methods the context is using and then throw exception on it through the MOQ framework, to be able to test your exception handling.

something like this, please check the syntax:

```
var mockContext = new Mock<IInventoryEF>();
mockContext.Setup(c=>c.SaveChanges()).Throws<Exception>();
```

As pointed out in another reply, you should also have either the `Attribute` for `ExpectedException` or if you use `FluentAssertions` you can also expect exceptions `inline`.

Comment: OK got article on dependency injection that may actually get through this grey matter. Thanks.

Comment: So wrt "You need to make the context injectable somehow (which is a part of different discussion). "

Comment: So wrt "You need to make the context injectable somehow (which is a part of different discussion). " Are you willing to entertain said discussion? According to James Shore, "Dependency injection means giving an object its instance variables." Source: http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html . I don't get it. Is this something you can speak or link to within the scope of this question?

Comment: It can be as simple as injecting the context or context factory in the Repository constructor. I meant there are many ways of doing it, the very basic idea is you can inject it to the class, instead of the class instantiating a new instance inline

Comment: Hold off on that answer. I just found some basic information on Pluralsight on IoC which seems to be a closely related topic (maybe even a superset of DI).

Comment: I really appreciate this help. I am not there yet. But you are leading me by the hand along the path. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to catch a specific exception, and you aren't using MOQ already, I'd suggest the `ExpectedExceptionAttribute`:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(IDNotFoundException))]
public void WhicheverTestMethod()
{
  ..
}
```

Where of course the type of exception can be whatever you want. I'm fairly sure you can check against the message as well.

In general, I'd also suggest not catching type `Exception` and getting the `InnerException` because there may be no inner exception, and you can't really test all possible exceptions because `Exception` is extendable.

Comment: I would recommend against using `ExpectedException` - there are [good reasons for avoiding it](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/01/17/unit-testing-and-expected-exceptions.aspx).

Comment: @ChrisMantle: That's a good point. In addition, if your shop likes code coverage too much, said attribute will reduce code coverage in a rather silly way. However, most of the disadvantages involve knowing which line threw the exception or dealing with multiple exceptions. Because a test should only be testing one thing, neither of these are truly convincing arguments, particularly if they require including more references or adding more code for only exception checking in a way that is only debatably advantageous.

Comment: My shop is me, myself and my pantry. And my mind grasping this stuff. I want to generate a test which will cause the exception to be thrown. But what I think I am hearing here is don't catch the exception. Allow it to be thrown up? I think there is some basic failure to understand good OOD. It has been more than a few years! Thanks.

Comment: @user2919960: I said not to catch `Exception`, not to avoid catching exceptions. That is a very large, important distinction. You should always constrain which exceptions you want to catch unless you're at the outermost point of your app and logging them.